# how to make the content become smaller while the browser become smaller

Tags: html, css, width

I was using media screen to made the content become smaller when reaching the specific width, my question is i want the content to float with the browser, I mean the content become smaller smoothly but not suddenly become smaller while reaching the width stated.

for example,
http://onepagelove.com/world-cup-match-balls

when the browser become smaller, the content will become small smoothly, but not in a sudden.
what is the coding for this?

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: KaiTi, "Arial Unicode MS";
font-size: 100%;
color: #000;
height:100%
}

html {
height:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.mainwrapper {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
height: 100%;
}

.container {
width: 936px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

.container {
width: 800px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left:auto;
}

#logo {
margin-left:280px
}

.content {
width:500px;
padding-left:110px;
padding-bottom:380px;
}

.footer {
margin-left: 62px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
color: #FFF;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#myFrame {
height: 200px;
width: 436px;
padding: 0;
}

}
```

Comment: It depends on what direction you are going. If you are developing mobile first min-width is a better approach, if you are scaling down your approach is fine, make sure to do some research on the subject before diving in, you will find you get much better results.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

Comment: @DanielTate thank you, i will look for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the width of the .container in % you don't need additional javascript to handle the transition. Just make it sure to specify a min-width, so that you content cannot become too narrow.

```
.container {
width: 90%;
min-width: 650px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on a right path with media queries, just instead of pixel (px) width use percent (%) width for content. 
You can also look at min-width, and max-width.